# Error in loading data for scatter plot in shinydashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I am trying to create scatter plot outputs in the shiny dashboard. I have similar datasets for several years, and I want to plot according to chosen variables and year. Datasets file name is *Y96Total8.rda, Y97Total8.rda*... Datasets name is *Total (data.table)*.

Unfortunately, I can't load the dataset in a true way to plot the results, and I have the error *"non-numeric argument to mathematical function"* in plot tab.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to produce this plot using the shiny dashboard it would be much appreciated.

I have attached the code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

header <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "green",
  dashboardHeader(title = "TEST"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    dir = "ltr",
    align = "right",
    menuItem("Correlation", tabName = "Correlation", icon = icon("users"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(load(file = "data/Test.rda"),
                dir = "ltr",
                tabItems(
                  tabItem(tabName = "Correlation",
                          fluidRow(tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel(
                              "Inputs",
                              box(
                                status = "danger",
                                solidHeader = TRUE,
                                width = 6,
                                title = "Food Expenditures Per",
                                sliderInput(
                                  inputId = "Food_Expenditures_Per2",
                                  label = "Food Expenditures",
                                  min = 0,
                                  max = 30000000,
                                  value = c(1000000, 10000000)
                                )
                              ),
                              box(
                                status = "danger",
                                solidHeader = TRUE,
                                title = "Total Expenditures Per",
                                width = 6,
                                sliderInput(
                                  inputId = "Total_Exp_Month_Per2",
                                  label = "Total Expenditures Per",
                                  min = 0,
                                  max = 100000000,
                                  value = c(1000000, 30000000)
                                )
                              ),
                              box(
                                status = "info",
                                solidHeader = TRUE,
                                title = "First Variable",
                                width = 6,
                                selectInput(
                                  "Var1",
                                  "First Variable",
                                  list("FoodExpenditure_Per", "Total_Exp_Month_Per"),
                                  selected =
                                    "FoodExpenditure_Per"
                                )
                              ),
                              box(
                                status = "info",
                                solidHeader = TRUE,
                                title = "Second Variable",
                                width = 6,
                                selectInput(
                                  "Var2",
                                  "Second Variable",
                                  list("FoodExpenditure_Per", "Total_Exp_Month_Per"),
                                  selected =
                                    "Total_Exp_Month_Per"
                                )
                              ),
                              box(
                                status = "info",
                                solidHeader = TRUE,
                                title = "Year",
                                width = 6,
                                selectInput(
                                  inputId = "slcT2Year3",
                                  label = "Year",
                                  choices =
                                    list(1390, 1391, 1392, 1393,
                                         1394, 1395, 1396, 1397),
                                  selected =
                                    1396
                                )
                              ),
                              box(
                                status = "info",
                                solidHeader = TRUE,
                                title = "Add line of best fit",
                                width = 6,
                                checkboxInput("fit", "Add line of best fit")
                              ),

                            ),
                            tabPanel(
                              "Plot"
                              ,
                              box(
                                status = "info",
                                solidHeader = TRUE,
                                width = 700,
                                height = 450,
                                plotOutput("scatterplot", width =
                                             600, height = 400)
                                ,
                                downloadButton("downloadPlot3", "Download")
                              )
                            )
                          )))
                ))
)


app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ##################### Scatter Plot #########################
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    y <- input$slcT2Year3
    fn3 <- paste0("data/Y", substr(y, 3, 4), "Total8.rda")
    load(fn3)

    Total <- subset(
      Total,
      FoodExpenditure_Per >= input$Food_Expenditures_Per2[1] &
        FoodExpenditure_Per <= input$Food_Expenditures_Per2[2] &
        Total_Exp_Month_Per >= input$Total_Exp_Month_Per2[1] &
        Total_Exp_Month_Per <= input$Total_Exp_Month_Per2[2]
    )


    p <- ggplot(Total, aes(input$Var1, input$Var2)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_log10()

    if (input$fit == TRUE) {
      p <- p + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
    }
    p
  })


  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
    #    q("no")
  })

}

shinyApp(header, app_server)
```

---

Image of the error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to produce a reprex, try to encase your y in a reactive function. all your inputs that get passed around should be reactives.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your code isn't really a minimal repoducable example.  if your problem is in the plot tab, it would be helpful if you removed everything that wasn't relevant to that specific tab.  That said, and without attempting to run your code 9there's too much of it), I'd suggest putting `req(input$slcT2Year3)` at the start of your `renderPlot` for the scatter plot.  Renderers (and any reactive) are triggered when the app starts.  If an input doesn't have a value at this point (and they usually don't), problems ensue.  And any other `input`s referenced in the renderer to the `req` call.

Comment: You really need to include a reprex.  As you did not provide a sample data that you are loading (Test.rda), it is hard to know what kind of data you have.  However, as suggested by others you need to use some reactive functions, `req` calls, and check and provide 'return(NULL)` when the input variable does not have a value at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ggplot` call should be changed to

```
p <- ggplot(Total, aes(Total[[input$Var1]], Total[[input$Var2]]))
```